# How to prevent plotly.figure_factory.create_table from transforming integers into float values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

def save_dataframe_as_image(df):

    fig =  ff.create_table(df)
    fig.write_image("image.png", scale=2)
```

The final image then contains only floats. How can I prevent the transformation from integer values into floats?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround, but you can cast df as a string when you pass it to your `save_dataframe_as_image` function.

This ensures the values in the table will display to the same precision as the df without actually modifying your df.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

def save_dataframe_as_image(df):
    fig =  ff.create_table(df)
    fig.write_image("image.png", scale=2)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SKU': [5,6,7],
    'Current Price': [24.7,65.22,149.99],
    'Sales': [45,15,15],
    'Return':[43,10,1],
    'Loss':[22,4,0],
    'Stock':[33,23,75]
})

save_dataframe_as_image(df.astype(str))
```

[image]